# Error with styled component import and eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

i got an error using styled component and eslint,

i want to use styled component in a separete files and i got an error

```
styledHeader' is defined but never used.
```

this is the whole component

```
import { styledHeader } from "./header.styled";

/**
 * return a JSX Element Header
 * @return {JSX.Element} <Header/>
 */
function Header() {
  return <styledHeader>
  </styledHeader>;
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: You need to: `return ( <styledHeader /> );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React component names must start with a capital letter.

It isn't used because you haven't used it as a valid component.

```
import { styledHeader as StyledHeader } from "./header.styled";

function Header() {
    return <StyledHeader></StyledHeader>;
}
```

Comment: Oh, i see it works now, thanks u so much, I didn't knew, that styled components has to be in capital letter

Comment: All component names must start with a capital letter. It is not unique to styled components.